# Freepascal. Как провести чтение дальше первой строки?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

> Код

```
program afile;
 uses crt;
        var
        f: text;
        a:string;
        i,k: byte;
begin
clrscr;
assign (f,'D:\\pascalpractic\\pr.txt');
reset(f);
readln(f,a);
write(a);

    For i:=1 to Length(a) do
     if a[i] in ['0'..'9'] then
     Begin
       inc(k);
       write(a[i]:2);
     End;
writeln;   writeln('кол-во цифр в файле = ',k);
   readln;
close(f);
end.
```

Содержимое файла:

> Hello world2013
>
> my program 300

происходит чтение и вычисление программы только с первой строкой
Как сделать чтобы читались и последующие строки символы цифры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     while not Eof(f) do
  begin
    ReadLn(f,a);
 // тут делаете что вам нужно
  end;
```

Comment: @savro
добавил но не работает и выскакитвает панелька
exited with exitcode = 103

    program afile;
 uses crt;
        var
        f: text;
        a:string;
        i,k: byte;

begin
clrscr;
assign (f,'D:\\pascalpractic\\pr.txt');
reset(f);
while not eof(f) do
begin
  readln(f,a);

write(a);

    For i:=1 to Length(a) do
     if a[i] in ['0'..'9'] then
     Begin
       inc(k);
       write(a[i]:2);
     End;
writeln;   writeln('æ¨äà ¢ áâà®ª¥ = ',k);
   readln;
close(f);

end;
end.

Comment: 103 ексит это не может найти файл, смотрите путь к файлу.

Comment: @savro
ошибка появляется после того как файл открывается и читается только первая строка
потом завершаем прогу и видем ошибку